# Using (this) with a class

Tags: jquery, this, jquery-hover

I have a jquery script that I need to show an image with a class on the hover state.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tooltip').hover(
  function() {$('.vidOvr').stop().fadeIn(750);} ,
  function() {$('.vidOvr').stop().fadeOut(500);})
});
```

I realized that I need a "this" in there somewhere so that the script doesn't trigger the image to show on ALL of the vidOver images on the page. I tried adding find:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tooltip').hover(
  function() {$(this).find('.vidOvr').stop().fadeIn(750);} ,
  function() {$(this).find('.vidOvr').stop().fadeOut(500);})
});
```

Without any luck. Also tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(this).find('.tooltip').hover(
  function() {$('.vidOvr').stop().fadeIn(750);} ,
  function() {$('.vidOvr').stop().fadeOut(500);})
});
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: What about just `$(this)..stop().fadeIn(750);}` ?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the HTML structure

Comment: how is your html? we need to know the parent/child relations here

Comment: Jquery is working fine..Post your html code..

Comment: fyi, you can select multiple classes: $('.tooltip, .vidOvr'), this makes your body description less complicated

Comment: you can also do this if you want: $(".tooltip > .vidOver") , where .tooltip is a parent container, and .vidOver is a child. Meh.. I'll put an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. Thanks to everyone for helping out. Just added ", this" after the class and it cleared up the issue.

```
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            $('.tooltip').hover(
              function() {$('.vidOvr', this).stop().fadeIn(100);} ,
              function() {$('.vidOvr', this).stop().fadeOut(100);})
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Please look at this jsfiddle, might gear you in the right direction, but it's kind of hard since I don't have any html to look at:

http://jsfiddle.net/M8c3F/

I removed the hover, because when fading out and in, it was difficult to get the elements back. So I replicated that behavior with mouseenter and mouseleave instead.

script:

```
$(function() {
    $(".tooltip").mouseenter(function() {
        $("> .vidOver", this).stop().fadeIn(750); //child class of (this element)
    });

    $(".tooltip > .vidOver").mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).stop().fadeOut(500);
    });
});
```

html code:

```
<div class="tooltip">parent container 1
    <div class="vidOver">child container 1</div>
    <div>child container 2</div></div>
<div class="tooltip">parent container 2
    <div class="vidOver">child container 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the attempt. I couldn't get it work, but my HTML is a little different:

<ul class="clearfix">
<li>
<a class="tooltip" href="/videos/draft-of-video/">
<span class="vidOvr" style="display:none">
<img src="youtubethumb.jpg">
</a>
</li>
</ul>

Comment: hey, I'd appreciate it if you'd upvote my answer if it ever contributed to your solution along with anyone else on here who helped.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but this just worked for me ...

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {

        $(".tooltip").hover(function() {
            $(this).find(".vidOver").stop().fadeIn(750);
        }, function() {
            $(this).find(".vidOver").stop().fadeOut(500);
        });

    });


</script>
```

... html

```
<div class="tooltip">HOVER ME <div class="vidOver" style="display: none;">HIII</div </div>
<div class="tooltip">DIFF HOVER ME <div class="vidOver" style="display: none;">SUP</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this instead

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tooltip').on('mouseenter', function() {
        $(this).find('.vidOver').stop(1,1).fadeIn();
    }).on('mouseleave', function() {
        $(this).find('.vidOver').stop(1,1).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

[**Examole Here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/XHzNb/1/)